# Generate a directory if a target name has a directory part

Tags: makefile, wildcard, gnu-make

I have this makefile code:

```
$(DIRS):
    @echo   "   MKDIR   build/tmp/base/socket/$@"
    $(Q)mkdir -p        $@/


%.a.s:
    @echo   "   CC  build/tmp/base/socket/$@"
    $(Q)$(CC) $(CFLAGS_A) -S $< -o $@
%.so.s:
    @echo   "   CC  build/tmp/base/socket/$@"
    $(Q)$(CC) $(CFLAGS_SO) -S $< -o $@
%.o: %.s
    @echo   "   AS  build/tmp/base/socket/$@"
    $(Q)$(AS) $< -o $@


tcp/client.a.s: $(TCP_CLIENT_SRC) $(TCP_CLIENT_INC)
tcp/client.so.s: $(TCP_CLIENT_SRC) $(TCP_CLIENT_INC)

tcp/server.a.s: $(TCP_SERVER_SRC) $(TCP_SERVER_INC)
tcp/server.so.s: $(TCP_SERVER_SRC) $(TCP_SERVER_INC)
```

I'd like to add a `| tcp` in the prerequisites of all targets that have a leading `tcp/` in their name, but I'd like to be able to do it in one line.  I wouldn't want to append that manually to every line that needs it.

I thought of adding this new rule:

```
tcp/%.s: | tcp
```

but it isn't doing anything.

I also thought of the more generic, which would be nicer, but same results:

```
%.s: | $(@D)
```

How should I write that?

---

A workaround would be to call mkdir every time (include it in both %.a.s and %.so.s rules), but that would add unnecessary calls to mkdir, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a fan of pattern rules. They are too arbitrary for my tastes.
(What actually happens depends on what files you may have lying around on your hard disk.)

> You cannot just add a prerequisite to a given set of targets using a pattern rule

Well you can if you use *[static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html)*. This is a much nicer idiom. Here we prefix a pattern rule with the actual list of sources you want the pattern rule to apply to. This is good where you can describe dependencies using *make*'s noddy pattern matching.

A sketch:

```
%.a: ; date >$@ # Pattern rule

tcp: ; mkdir -p $@ # Explicit rule

tcp/a.a: tcp/%.a: | tcp ; # Static pattern rule!

.PHONY: all
all: tcp/a.a
all: c.a
all: dir/b.a
all: ; : $@ Success
```

And we have:

```
$ make all
mkdir -p tcp
date >tcp/a.a
date >c.a
date >dir/b.a
/bin/sh: dir/b.a: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:3: dir/b.a] Error 1
```

Here we have told *make* that before it builds (i.e., "runs the recipe for") `tcp/a.a`, it must first build `tcp`. That works. We didn't tell *make* about the directory for `dir/b.a`, so that failed. Note that the `.a` file's recipe is still in an ordinary pattern rule. This is just by way of exposition. I would definitely change this.

Yeah, in this case the pattern rule for `tcp/` is over-the-top. Consider though that before you create `tcp/a.a`, you might first need to create a `auto/a.src` (say).

```
tcp/a.a: tcp/%.a: auto/%.src | tcp ; # Static pattern rule!
```

Easily extensible.

```
targets := tcp/a.a tcp/b.a tcp/c.a
${targets}: tcp/%.a: auto/%.src | tcp ; # Static pattern rule!
```

[By the way, in your original makefile, your archive and shared object should depend on the `.o` files, not the source (???)]

Comment: About your BTW question: See the last extension. Those are assembly files.  The difference between both is that `CFLAGS_SO` has `-fpic`, while `CFLAGS_A` doesn't.  So from .a.s files I'll assemble .a.o object files, which will be archived into a .a library.  And from .so.s files I'll assemble .so.o object files, which will be compiled into a .so library.

Comment: If I pass the whole list of objects instead of just the ones starting with tcp, will it still work (ignoring those that don't match the pattern, i.e. don't start with tcp)?: `$(OBJS): tcp/%.a: | tcp ; # Static pattern`

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Not unreasonably, each source filename has to match the target pattern. `file.o: %.c: %.auto …` ain't gonna work.

Comment: Well, you have the same issues with static pattern rules as with pattern rules: a static pattern rule is an explicit rule, which must have a recipe just like a pattern rule must have a recipe.  What the OP wanted to do was use a pattern rule to add a prerequisite to an _already-existing_ target.  You can't do that, and you can't do it with static pattern rules either.  You may prefer one over the other but beyond preference there's nothing about this question that gives static pattern rules any advantage.

Comment: @bobbogo sorry, typo cause of cp&paste.  I meant `$(OBJS): tcp/%.o: | tcp ;` where `OBJS = tcp/foo.o dir/bar.o`.  I would expect this to run the `tcp` target for the first object, and ignore the second one without failing.

Comment: @MadScientist This answer works with existing targets.  I'll show the full Makefile as a new answer to show it working.  It's very interesting, I think.

Comment: @MadScientist Yes, it's an explicit dependency, but it doesn't have to have a recipe. This is in the same way that you can have many ordinary non-pattern dependency lines.

Comment: "*each source filename has to match the target pattern*": Partly true: Although you said it due to my typo, and I understand the reason, this sentence isn't entirely true, and the following explanation might help future readers: if none of the targets (the leftmost part in the `... : ... : ... | ...` structure) matches the pattern (the second part), then make fails, but if at least one of them matches the pattern, then make will apply the rule to only those that match, ignoring those that don't. This is very powerful, and an example is in my answer to this question. Very nice feature! Thanks!!

Comment: @CacahueteFrito That is an error. _Make_ will always complain. _Make_ will still use the recipe (unless it's overridden elswhere), but things like `$<` will be empty. _Don't do this!_

Comment: @bobbogo Is it?  For some reason make is happy with my code. I guess this should be a new question.  I'll ask it.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito In the makefile you presented, the file _does_ match the pattern because you used `tcp/%`, which as a wildcard matches _every_ filename. Nice.

Comment: By the way, it looks like _make_ supports as many of these static pattern dependency lines as you fancy. This is really useful.

Comment: @bobbogo No.  I added an empty foo file which isn't in tcp/ to test that.  I thought it didn't complain, but I might have not saved after doing that because now it is complaining.  I'll experiment things to be able to do that.

Comment: Maybe the way to go is to use a normal rule for $(NEEDDIR), and in that rule, put as an order only dependency all the subdirectories needed.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just add a prerequisite to a given set of targets using a pattern rule.  That's not how pattern rules work: they are *rules*: they must have a recipe associated with them.  A pattern rule without a recipe actually *deletes* that pattern rule (see [Canceling Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html)).

You can either create two sets of pattern rules, one for all targets and a second one for just targets that start with `tcp/` that have an extra prerequisite, but you have to write the entire pattern rule twice, including a recipe, not just the pattern line.

Or just put the `mkdir` into the recipe.  A `mkdir` on a directory that already exists won't even be noticeable.

Comment: Just to be ridiculously obvious, you should be using `mkdir -p` to make sure you don't get failures during parallel builds etc.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is only to show a working Makefile implementing @bobbogo 's answer.

This Makefile is a leaf of a Makefile tree, so all variables not defined here are exported by upper Makefiles.

`Makefile`:

```
#! /usr/bin/make -f

################################################################################
# *AUTHOR*
# FULL NAME     "Alejandro Colomar Andrés"
################################################################################

################################################################################

DIRS    =                               \
        $(CURDIR)/tcp

OBJ     =                                                               \
        $(CURDIR)/tcp/client.o                                          \
        $(CURDIR)/tcp/server.o                                        \
        $(CURDIR)/foo.o

SRC     =                                                               \
        $(SRC_DIR)/base/socket/tcp/client.c                             \
        $(SRC_DIR)/base/socket/tcp/server.c                             \
        $(SRC_DIR)/base/socket/foo.c

DEP             = $(OBJ:.o=.d)
BOTH_OBJ        = $(subst .a.o,.a.o ,$(join $(OBJ:.o=.a.o),$(OBJ:.o=.so.o)))
BOTH_ASM        = $(subst .a.s,.a.s ,$(join $(OBJ:.o=.a.s),$(OBJ:.o=.so.s)))
NEEDDIR         = $(DEP) $(BOTH_ASM)

################################################################################

PHONY := all
all: $(BOTH_OBJ)
        @:

$(DIRS): $(CURDIR)/%:
    @echo   "   MKDIR   build/tmp/base/socket/$*"
    $(Q)mkdir -p        $@

$(NEEDDIR): | $(DIRS)

$(CURDIR)/%.d: $(SRC_DIR)/base/socket/%.c
        @echo   "       CC -M   build/tmp/base/socket/$*.d"
        $(Q)$(CC) $(CFLAGS_A) -MG -MT"$@"                               \
                        -MT"$(CURDIR)/$*.a.s" -MT"$(CURDIR)/$*.so.s"    \
                        -M $< -MF $@
$(CURDIR)/%.a.s: $(SRC_DIR)/base/socket/%.c $(CURDIR)/%.d
        @echo   "       CC      build/tmp/base/socket/$*.a.s"
        $(Q)$(CC) $(CFLAGS_A) -S $< -o $@
$(CURDIR)/%.so.s: $(SRC_DIR)/base/socket/%.c $(CURDIR)/%.d
        @echo   "       CC      build/tmp/base/socket/$*.so.s"
        $(Q)$(CC) $(CFLAGS_SO) -S $< -o $@
$(CURDIR)/%.o: $(CURDIR)/%.s
        @echo   "       AS      build/tmp/base/socket/$*.o"
        $(Q)$(AS) $< -o $@

include $(DEP)


PHONY += clean
clean:
        $(Q)rm -rf *.o *.s *.d
################################################################################
# Declare the contents of the PHONY variable as phony.
.PHONY: $(PHONY)


################################################################################
######## End of file ###########################################################
################################################################################
```

output:

```
    MKDIR   build/tmp/base/socket/tcp
    CC -M   build/tmp/base/socket/foo.d
    CC -M   build/tmp/base/socket/tcp/server.d
    CC -M   build/tmp/base/socket/tcp/client.d
    CC  build/tmp/base/socket/tcp/client.a.s
    AS  build/tmp/base/socket/tcp/client.a.o
    CC  build/tmp/base/socket/tcp/client.so.s
    AS  build/tmp/base/socket/tcp/client.so.o
    CC  build/tmp/base/socket/tcp/server.a.s
    AS  build/tmp/base/socket/tcp/server.a.o
    CC  build/tmp/base/socket/tcp/server.so.s
    AS  build/tmp/base/socket/tcp/server.so.o
    CC  build/tmp/base/socket/foo.a.s
    AS  build/tmp/base/socket/foo.a.o
    CC  build/tmp/base/socket/foo.so.s
    AS  build/tmp/base/socket/foo.so.o
```